# Hibernate session.createSQLQuery

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I have two projects, maven.

- A - rest app, using hibernate 5.2.16.FINAL, including B (excluding its hibernate)
- B - library, using hibernate 4.3.9

Project A creates own context which imports DBConfig (copy of Bs) replacing B`s one to use proper **hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager, hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean**

Project A makes call to service in B -> DAO -> get session -> createSQLQuery. 
This fails with

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.createSQLQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/SQLQuery;
```

When I change hibernate to 5.2.16 in B without any further code changes it works or if I move *DAO* from B to A (also with proper configuration in Context - including moved DAO and excluding one from B - because of bean name duplication) it also works ?!

How is that possible ? I really don't understand or miss something. Without any code changes on project B just with configuration of maven hibernate dependency (which is excluded in A as I said above) the code either run or fail on DAO.createSQLQuery.

Any idea from somebody ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to compile both projects using the same Hibernate version.

Why `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` occurs in your case: `createSQLQuery` is defined slightly differently in 4.3 (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/SharedSessionContract.html) and 5.2 (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/QueryProducer.html). Note the return type is different.

At compile time, the method call is resolved correctly if either version is used. This is because the return type used by 5.2 (`NativeQuery`) extends the one used by 4.3 (`SQLQuery`). However, once B is compiled with 4.3, it refers to `createSQLQuery` defined by 4.3 (`SQLQuery createSQLQuery(String)`) and that can't be found in 5.2, that you use at runtime.

Comment: thought so it can have something with compilation

Comment: comparing bytecode actually showed this pretty nice. thank you once more